# How do I access a single field while using For Loop to iterate through all the fields of a ModelForm in Django Template?

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a model which has four ForeignKey fields, so they are dropdown fields in the form.

```
class Package(models.Model):
    patient=models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=CASCADE)
    diagnosis=models.ForeignKey(Diagnosis, on_delete=CASCADE)
    treatment=models.ForeignKey(Treatment, on_delete=CASCADE)
    patient_type=models.ForeignKey(PatientType, on_delete=CASCADE)
    date_of_admission=models.DateField(default=None)
    max_fractions=models.IntegerField(default=None)
    total_package=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

**The forms.py:**

```
class PackageForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Package
        fields='__all__'
        widgets={
           "patient_type" : forms.Select(attrs={"onblur":"mf();"}),
           "max_fractions" : forms.NumberInput(attrs={"onfocus":"mf();", "onblur":"tp();"}),
           "total_package" : forms.NumberInput(attrs={"onfocus":"tp();", "onblur":"onLoad();"}),
           'date_of_admission': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
```

**The views.py:**

```
def package_view(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        fm_package=PackageForm(request.POST, prefix='package_form')
        if fm_package.is_valid():
            package=fm_package.save()
            IpdReport.objects.create(patient=package.patient, package=package)
            fm_package=PackageForm(prefix='package_form')
        return render (request, 'account/package.html', {'form5':fm_package})
    else:
        fm_package=PackageForm(prefix='package_form')
        return render (request, 'account/package.html', {'form5':fm_package})
```

**The Template:**

```
<form action="" method="post" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form5.non_field_errors}}
        {% for fm in form5 %}
        <div>
            {{fm.label_tag}}
            {{fm}}
            <span>{{fm.errors|striptags}}</span><br><br>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit" id="savebtn">Save</button>
    </form>
```

Now, what I want is to insert an Anchor Tag next to all the foreign_key fields, in the template, to add a new object into the original table. For example, an Add Patient option next to the Patient's dropdown field, when clicked, a new, small window would show up with Patient form. The user enters the new patient's data, saves it and the same name shows up in the dropdown.

But as I am using a For Loop in the template, how would I be able to access those foreign key fields and apply the options? Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it isn't a problem I would move away from rendering all of the fields with the 'forloop'. Instead I would use notation: form.field to render different fields. So it would look like:

```
{{ form.patient.label_tag }}
{{ form.patient }}
```

It should be much easier to navigate through fields this way, but of course it will require more typing :)